# How to pull a subnet id based on the cidr block in terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have create vpc and 3 subnets in a region.I have 3 services named jsc,valid,test and i have to create 3 instances for each service and i have to pass subnet id from each zone cidr block

```
variable "region" {
  type    = string
  default = "ap-south-1"
}
variable "ecom-cidr" {
  type    = string
  default = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

variable "azs" {
  type    = list(any)
  default = ["ap-south-1a", "ap-south-1b", "ap-south-1c"]
}

variable "private-subnets" {
  type    = list(any)
  default = ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/24", "10.0.3.0/24"]
}

variable "public-subnets" {
  type    = list(any)
  default = ["10.0.4.0/28", "10.0.5.0/28", "10.0.6.0/28"]
}


variable "instance_count" {
  type    = string
  default = 3
}

variable "service-names" {
  type    = list(any)
  default = ["valid", "jsc", "test"]

}
resource "aws_subnet" "ecom-private" {
  count                   = length(var.private-subnets)
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.ecom-vpc.id
  cidr_block              = element(var.private-subnets, count.index)
  availability_zone       = element(var.azs, count.index)
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
  tags = {
    Name = "ecom-INT-${element(split("-", element(var.azs, count.index)), 2)}"
  }
}

data "aws_subnet" "priv-subnet-details" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.ecom-vpc.id
  count                   = length(var.private-subnets)
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["ecom-INT-${element(split("-", element(var.azs, count.index)), 2)}"] # insert values here
  }
  
}
```

Now i have to pass the subnet id to below aws instance resource by either lookup a Name Tag or cidr block

```
 resource "aws_instance" "ecom-instances" {
    
      count = 3*var.instance_count
    
      ami           = data.aws_ami.ecom.id
      instance_type = "t3.micro"
      subnet_id = <how to fetch>
      tags = {
        Name = "ecom-${element(var.service-names, count.index)}-service"
        Service = "${element(var.service-names, count.index)}"
      }
vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.ecom-sg["${element(var.service-names, count.index)}"].id]
```

Subnet details from data source is as below

```
subnet-details = [
      + {
          + arn                             = "arn:aws:ec2:ap-south-1:114712064551:subnet/subnet-07fede319193c390d"
          + assign_ipv6_address_on_creation = false
          + availability_zone               = "ap-south-1a"
          + availability_zone_id            = "aps1-az1"
          + available_ip_address_count      = 251
          + cidr_block                      = "10.0.1.0/24"
          + customer_owned_ipv4_pool        = ""
          + default_for_az                  = false
          + filter                          = [
              + {
                  + name   = "tag:Name"
                  + values = [
                      + "ecom-INT-1a",
                    ]
                },
            ]
          + id                              = "subnet-07fede319193c390d"
          + ipv6_cidr_block                 = null
          + ipv6_cidr_block_association_id  = null
          + map_customer_owned_ip_on_launch = false
          + map_public_ip_on_launch         = false
          + outpost_arn                     = ""
          + owner_id                        = "114712064551"
          + state                           = "available"
          + tags                            = {
              + "Name" = "ecom-INT-1a"
            }
          + vpc_id                          = "vpc-0fd6cb4be13de15e8"
        },
      + {
          + arn                             = "arn:aws:ec2:ap-south-1:114712064551:subnet/subnet-0680314588bcd64e6"
          + assign_ipv6_address_on_creation = false
          + availability_zone               = "ap-south-1b"
          + availability_zone_id            = "aps1-az3"
          + available_ip_address_count      = 251
          + cidr_block                      = "10.0.2.0/24"
          + customer_owned_ipv4_pool        = ""
          + default_for_az                  = false
          + filter                          = [
              + {
                  + name   = "tag:Name"
                  + values = [
                      + "ecom-INT-1b",
                    ]
                },
            ]
          + id                              = "subnet-0680314588bcd64e6"
          + ipv6_cidr_block                 = null
          + ipv6_cidr_block_association_id  = null
          + map_customer_owned_ip_on_launch = false
          + map_public_ip_on_launch         = false
          + outpost_arn                     = ""
          + owner_id                        = "114712064551"
          + state                           = "available"
          + tags                            = {
              + "Name" = "ecom-INT-1b"
            }
          + vpc_id                          = "vpc-0fd6cb4be13de15e8"
        },
      + {
          + arn                             = "arn:aws:ec2:ap-south-1:114712064551:subnet/subnet-04f6ab1d3612c4f48"
          + assign_ipv6_address_on_creation = false
          + availability_zone               = "ap-south-1c"
          + availability_zone_id            = "aps1-az2"
          + available_ip_address_count      = 251
          + cidr_block                      = "10.0.3.0/24"
          + customer_owned_ipv4_pool        = ""
          + default_for_az                  = false
          + filter                          = [
              + {
                  + name   = "tag:Name"
                  + values = [
                      + "ecom-INT-1c",
                    ]
                },
            ]
          + id                              = "subnet-04f6ab1d3612c4f48"
          + ipv6_cidr_block                 = null
          + ipv6_cidr_block_association_id  = null
          + map_customer_owned_ip_on_launch = false
          + map_public_ip_on_launch         = false
          + outpost_arn                     = ""
          + owner_id                        = "114712064551"
          + state                           = "available"
          + tags                            = {
              + "Name" = "ecom-INT-1c"
            }
          + vpc_id                          = "vpc-0fd6cb4be13de15e8"
        },
    ]
```

Could you please guide me

Tried the below method but since for_each is containing the subnet id's which compute after apply,terraform is throwing error.So i want to directly pass the subnet-id instead of using for each

```
locals {
  instance_configs = tomap({
    for idx,pair in setproduct(var.service-names, data.aws_subnet.priv-subnet-details.*.id) :
    "${pair[0]}-${pair[1]}" => {
      service_name = pair[0]
      subnet = pair[1]
    }
  })
}

resource "aws_instance" "ecom-instances" {
   for_each = local.instance_configs
  ami           = data.aws_ami.ecom.id
  instance_type = "t3.micro"
  tags = {
    Name = "ecom-${each.value.service_name}-service"
    Service = each.value.service_name
  }
vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.ecom-sg[each.value.service_name].id]
subnet_id              = each.value.subnet
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify: Are you using the `data "aws_subnet" "priv-subnet-details" {...}` block to read out details of the subnets that you are creating with the `resource "aws_subnet" "ecom-private" {...}` block? Secondly, you say you want to pass "the subnet ID" - which subnet ID? You have several subnets.

Comment: And why are you creating `3 * var.instance_count` instances?

Comment: Which subnets? You have priv-subnet-details and ecom-private? What's the difference?

Comment: @marcin priv-subnet-details is just a data source of ecom-private

Comment: @lxop I need to create 3 instance on each service(3) and each avail zone has 1 priv subnet.So I want to create 3 * (each zone priv subnet) * 3 (services - valid,jsc,test)=9 instances

Comment: @user10912187 Why not create 3 autoscaling groups, as it usually would be done? Each ASG would have desired count of 3.

Comment: @Marcin sure marcin if we are not able to then i will go with that option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it sounds like your problem could be modeled more directly as a map of objects where each element represents the settings for a particular availability zone:

```
variable "availability_zones" {
  type = map(object({
    private_subnet = string
    public_subnet  = string
  }))
}
```

You could then assign this a value like the following in order to clearly indicate which CIDR ranges belong to which availability zones:

```
  availability_zones = {
    ap-south-1a = {
      private_subnet = "10.0.1.0/24"
      public_subnet  = "10.0.4.0/28"
    }
    ap-south-1b = {
      private_subnet = "10.0.2.0/24"
      public_subnet  = "10.0.5.0/28"
    }
    ap-south-1c = {
      private_subnet = "10.0.3.0/24"
      public_subnet  = "10.0.6.0/28"
    }
  }
```

Now you have a data structure that directly matches the expectations of `for_each` to create these subnets. For example, for your private subnets:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "ecom_private" {
  for_each = var.availability_zones

  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.ecom-vpc.id
  cidr_block              = each.value.private_subnet
  availability_zone       = each.key
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
  tags = {
    Name = "ecom-INT-${split("-", each.key)[2]}"
  }
}
```

An advantage of this approach is that `aws_subnet.ecom_private` is now a map from availability zones to subnet objects. As I mentioned in my answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67435352/281848), a particular Terraform configuration should typically not read back with a `data` block the same objects it's also managing with `resource` blocks; instead, we refer to the results of the `resource` blocks directly so that Terraform can see how the objects are connected and thus produce the correct order of operations.

For the second part of your problem it sounds like you want to declare an `aws_instance` instance per service *and* per subnet. To achieve that with `for_each` we need to derive a new data structure that has one element per combination of service and subnet. To find all combinations of two sets I'd typically use [the `setproduct` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/setproduct.html), which in this case we might use like this:

```
locals {
  service_subnets = {
    for pair in setproduct(var.service_names, values(aws_subnet.ecom_private)) :
    "${pair[0]}:${pair[1].availability_zone}" => {
      service_name = pair[0]
      subnet       = pair[1]
    }
  }
}
```

This expression creates a mapping from compound keys containing both a service name and an availability zone name to objects containing both the service name and one of the subnet objects. This data structure is now of a suitable shape to declare `aws_instance` per element of this collection. Note that this is different than what you tried because the keys are built only from data defined directly in the configuration: service names and availability zone names. Your example didn't work because you tried to use the subnet id, which EC2 doesn't decide until after the subnet has already been created.

```
resource "aws_instance" "ecom" {
  for_each = local.service_subnets

  ami           = data.aws_ami.ecom.id
  instance_type = "t3.micro"
  subnet_id     = each.value.subnet.id

  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.ecom_sg[each.value.service_name].id]

  tags = {
    Name    = "ecom-${each.value.service_name}-service"
    Service = each.value.service_name
  }
}
```

These instances will therefore have addresses like this, where the keys include only data that you've defined directly in your configuration:

- `aws_instance.ecom["valid:ap-south-1a"]`
- `aws_instance.ecom["valid:ap-south-1b"]`
- `aws_instance.ecom["valid:ap-south-1c"]`
- `aws_instance.ecom["jsc:ap-south-1a"]`
- `aws_instance.ecom["jsc:ap-south-1b"]`
- `aws_instance.ecom["jsc:ap-south-1c"]`
- `aws_instance.ecom["test:ap-south-1a"]`
- `aws_instance.ecom["test:ap-south-1b"]`
- `aws_instance.ecom["test:ap-south-1c"]`

Comment: awesome martin thanks for the guidance and good learning for me